# Run ssh-add in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a Gitlab pipeline, in which I want to create a connection to a server with ssh:

```
stages:
  - connect

connect-ssh:
  stage: connect
  script:
    - mkdir ~/.ssh
    - echo -e "$PROD_SSH_KEY" > file_rsa        # SSH PRIVATE KEY
    - echo -e "$PROD_SSH_PASSPHRASE" > passfile # PASSPHRASE
    - chmod 600 file_rsa
    - cat passfile | ssh-add file_rsa           # DOESN'T WORK
    - ssh -i $PROD_USER@$PROD_HOST
    - pwd
```

> $ cat passfile | ssh-add group-5_rsa
> Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

I have seen few answer, but they weren't appropriate with gitlab jobs.
What solution do I have for *this* situation?

Comment: You might just need to start your ssh-agent as it is not running within your gitlab-runner. try executing  `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` before using ssh-add

Comment: Yes now I understand what it helps me do, the thing is ssh-add didn't let me enter the passphrase, but eval $(ssh-agent -s) make sure it listening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach was illustrated in [gitlab-org/gitlab-runner issue 2418](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/2418)

- putting the commands in a script, including the `eval $(ssh-agent -s)`
- *sourcing* said script

> calling a script like you did, opens a sub-shell. The ssh agent environment is therefore not available in the outer shell.
> Sourcing the scripts, however, executes it in the current shell. This also means you should be careful with what you do in that scripts. You can overwrite environment variables, exit the main shell, etc.

In your case, just adding `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` might be enough, since sourcing the script would be the same as running those commands line by line in `.gitlab-ci.yml` itself.

Comment: Hello, I don't understand why adding eval $(ssh-agent -s) might be enough, it's just calling ssh-agent, is it not? how does it get the passphrase and input it in ssh-add?
I looked at the gitlab-runner and doesn't understand it either, it doesn't use the passphrase, is it useless? Thank you for your answer

Comment: @HamzaInce It makes sure the agent is started and listening: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/2418 is a good example.